# How to require a letter or a number after the special character?

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regex for specific format of email addresses:

Before the `@` sign:

- Allow only English letters and numbers.
- Allow dots, dashes and underscores as long as they are not
  consecutive, and don't allow them to be the last in the string (They
  have to followed by a letter or a number)

After the `@` sign:

- Allow only single dot
- TLD has to be minimum 2 letters (currently I also set to 24 maximum
  but that doesn't matter)

I also allow spaces before and after the entire string (And later trim them)

I managed to get to a working regex that almost matches everything above, except for the part where the special characters (dots, dashes and underscores) have to be followed by a letter or a number.

so this is the regex that works:

```
/^\s*(?!.*[._-]{2})[\w\.-]+@([\w-])+\.+[\w-]{2,24}\s*$/
```

Then I tried adding the part that matches with a letter or a number after the special char but it breaks everything:

```
(?=[A-Z\d])
```

So it looks: `/^\s*(?!.*[._-]{2})[\w\.-]+(?=[A-Z\d])+@([\w-])+\.+[\w-]{2,24}\s*$/`

But that doesn't work

Test data:

```
### Should match:
email@domain.com
email_2@domain.com
email.three@domain.com
email-four@domain.com
 email_with_spaces@domain.com

### Should not match but still matches:
email.@domain.com

## Should not match and doesn't match (so working correctly):
email@domain.com.net
email@,domain.com
```

demo: https://regex101.com/r/qYMQlt/1

Comment: But can there be a "special" character at the start of the string, or right after the `@` character or before/after the `.`?

Comment: Might it not be easier to split on the `@` sign and then validate the two parts separately?  If there is no `@` sign, then the returned array would be length of 1.

Comment: @Thefourthbird I am learning regex as I work so I would like to see both options in case the spec would change (Right now it does allow special char and right after the `@` but you are right, it might not be allowed. WJS can you show me how? I am new to regex. I just did what I could and of course it can be better and I'd like to learn new ways

Comment: Perhaps like this `^\s*[^\W_]+(?:[._-][^\W_]+)*@[^\W_]+(?:[_-][^\W_]+)*\.[\w-]{2,24}\s*$` https://regex101.com/r/ID1UaR/1

Comment: For the 1st part you could use something like `^\s*[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[._-][A-Za-z0-9]+)*@`, but for the 2nd part I'm not quite sure what your exact requirements are.

Comment: @Thefourthbird this is really good. Can you please explain the changes? And, what would you do for example if I wanted to allow it to have special char right after the @ but prevent it right before the `@`?

Comment: @TheArchitect Then you might using an optional character class allowing all variations for a single character after the @ `^\s*[^\W_]+(?:[._-][^\W_]+)*@[._w-]?[^\W_]+(?:[_-][^\W_]+)*\.[\w-]{2,24}\s*$` https://regex101.com/r/EkzBkN/1 Note that `[\w-]{2,24}` could also allow `---------------`

Comment: Why are you creating your own validation for email addresses? Have you tried any existing code?

Comment: Not needed ? Deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a negated character class `[^\W_]` to match word characters without the `_`

To not match 2 special characters in a row you don't have to use a negative lookahead `(?!.*[._-]{2})`, but you can repeat matching using a group and start with the "special" character followed by at least 1 or more times other characters.

- `^` Start of string
- `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars
- `[^\W_]+` Match 1+ times a word char without the underscore
- `(?:[._-][^\W_]+)*` Optionally repeat the same, but allow a single char `.` `_` `-`
- `@` Match literally
- `[^\W_]+` Match 1+ times a word char without the underscore
- `(?:[_-][^\W_]+)*` Optionally repeat the same, but allow a single char `.` `_` `-`
- `\.[\w-]{2,24}` Match `.` and repeat matching 2-24 times either a word char or `-` *(Note that this can also match 24 times a hyphen, perhaps use `[a-z]{2,}`)*
- `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ID1UaR/1)

Comment: thank you! I changed the last part to `[a-zA-Z]{2,}`. looks like everything is OK! My only confusion is regarding `[^\W_]+`, because from what I understand, `\W` the complement of  `\w`, so meaning matching any non-alphanumeric character, then doesn't `\W_` mean any non alphanumeric character and and underscore? But in this case it actually IS alphanumeric

Comment: @TheArchitect Using `\W` means non word characters. But using `[^\W_]` is a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) so it  matches word characters except an underscore.